# (Debian) How to fix whatever nVidia's driver did to usb 2.0

Tags: debian, usb, nvidia

OS: Debian Stretch
Motherboard: Foxconn G33M02
I installed the package nvidia-driver using the instructions at
https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers
and on reboot, got a looping "over current" error from all usb 2.0 ports that had anything in them (the keyboard and mouse are usb on this mobo). I followed the page's instructions for "Backing out in case of failure", reverting to the Nouveau driver, but the "over current" error remains. After booting the kernel, a second looping error joins the fray: "unable to enumerate". How to get the usb ports functional again now?

Comment: edit the question and add your results like " Edit 1 : The it fixed itself after 30 reboots, explaination ? ", let the community analyse the problem. That might further help us to fix the Deb. Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed itself after about 30 reboots.